# resizable select option dropdown help

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I'm using this plugin http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ and it works awesome!! but I'd like to make the select dropdown boxes resize able using the jquery ui library. when i try it i end up with two select boxes. I'm still learning jquery but is this case where i would use bind? or delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the pluging that you said, but try to do this:

```
$("#multiselect-demo").multiselect({
   selectedText: "# of # selected"
});
```

`$('#multiselect-demo')` is your own select dropdown box. And then:

```
$('#multiselect-demo').resizable();
```

If it doesn't work like you want, try this instead:

`$('.multiselect-menu').resizable();`

I hope it helps. Happy codding!

PS: remember that you can change `resizable` behaviour. See [documentation and examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) for more information about this.